# Complex-recursive stack effects?

Tags: recursion, tail-recursion, factor-lang

```
USING: accessors html.parser.analyzer io kernel math namespaces
  present regexp sequences ;
IN: all-roads-to-wiki

SYMBOL: G

: match-good-pages ( a -- ?/f )
  R/ \/wiki\/[^:]*$/ first-match ;

: filter-urls ( tags -- urls )
  find-hrefs [ present ]     map
  [ match-good-pages ]       filter
  [ match-good-pages seq>> ] map ;

: findpath ( url -- url )
  G get =
  [
     ! false
  ]
  [ scrape-html nip
    [
      dup "title" find-by-name drop 1 + swap nth
      text>> R/ - Wikipedia,/ re-split first print
    ]
    [
      "bodyContent" find-by-id-between filter-urls [ findpath ] map
    ] bi
  ] if ; inline recursive

: allroads-entry ( -- a )
  readln "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/" prepend G set-global
  "enwp.org/Special:Random" findpath ; inline
```

The above code will recurse over every link on Wikipedia until it finds the one it's looking for.

That's okay, because (hopefully) `findpath` will eventually "return" (i.e. not call itself again) and leave a huge nested data structure on the stack. But when  I try to compile this, I get an [`unbalanced-recursion`](http://docs.factorcode.org/content/word-unbalanced-recursion-error,stack-checker.errors.html) error:

> The recursive word “findpath” leaves with the stack having the wrong height
>
> `unbalanced-recursion`: Thrown when stack effect inference determines that an inline recursive word has an incorrect stack effect declaration.

No matter what I do, Factor (understandably) complains about the stack effect not matching up. What do I have to do to get this to recurse properly?

Comment: 1-  `drop f` in the false branch, and `sift` to remove falses in the list, if I understand correctly. 2- I think it's missing a `dup` before `G get =` (as the = consumes the url). 3- Are you sure the recursion ends? Won't the list keep growing forever?

Comment: Isn't this like a depth-first search on the graphs of the links? If you find a cycle somewhere you'll be stuck there forever!

Comment: @fedes. you're probably right, but it's just supposed to work like the recursive solution: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/34662/find-a-route-between-two-wikipedia-articles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look closely at the `find-path` word. I'll add comments so that you can see what is on the stack:

```
: findpath ( url -- url )
    ! 1 item: { url }
    G 
    ! 2 items: { url G }
    get 
    ! 2 items: { url value-of-G }
    =
    ! 1: item { t/f }
    [
       ! 0 items!!!!
       ! false
    ]
    [ scrape-html nip
        [
            dup "title" find-by-name drop 1 + swap nth
            text>> R/ - Wikipedia,/ re-split first print
        ]
        [
            "bodyContent" find-by-id-between filter-urls 
            [ findpath ] map
        ] bi
    ] if ; inline recursive
```

The `if` combinator consumes the last item on the stack so this code can't possibly work. Here is working code for the `findpath` word:

```
: page-title ( seq -- title )
    dup "title" find-by-name drop 1 + swap nth
    text>> R/ - Wikipedia,/ re-split first ;

: page-links ( seq -- links )
    "bodyContent" find-by-id-between filter-urls ;

: scrape-en-wiki-url ( wiki-url -- seq )
    "https://en.wikipedia.org" prepend
    dup print flush scrape-html nip ;

: found-url? ( wiki-url -- ? )
    G get [ = ] [ drop t ] if* ;

: findpath ( wiki-url -- seq/f )
    dup found-url?
    [ drop f G set f ] [
        scrape-en-wiki-url
        [ page-title print flush ] [
            page-links [ findpath ] map
        ] bi
    ] if ; inline recursive
```

Also  take a look at the [Wikipedia vocab](https://github.com/factor/factor/blob/master/extra/wikipedia/wikipedia.factor) which is meant for tasks like these.